# Java Null Pointer Exception in a File Reading Android Application

Tags: android

I am new to android app development and I am developing an android app to read a .txt file containing spectrum data. The file contains integers and white spaces,so after reading every line the code trims the string to remove the white spaces and then converts the string containing string to integers The integers represents Y coordinate value and the line number represents X coordinate value. I have to plot a Scatter graph and I am using Achartengine for the same. When I try running the application on the emulator the app crashes. The Log cat gives this information

```
06-22 09:08:58.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-22 09:08:58.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.spec1readertest/com.example.spec1readertest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 09:08:58.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
06-22 09:08:58.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
06-22 09:08:58.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-22 09:08:58.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
06-22 09:08:58.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-22 09:08:58.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-22 09:08:58.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
06-22 09:08:58.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 09:08:58.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-22 09:08:58.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
06-22 09:08:58.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-22 09:08:58.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-22 09:08:58.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 09:08:58.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at com.example.spec1readertest.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:89)
06-22 09:08:58.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
06-22 09:08:58.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5143)
06-22 09:08:58.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
06-22 09:08:58.114: E/AndroidRuntime(1015):     ... 11 more
```

This is the Main activity.java file

```
package com.example.spec1readertest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ScatterGraphPlot scatter;
    GraphicalView view;
    LinearLayout layout;
    EditText filename;
    String filepath;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        filename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filename);

        // Initialize loadspec btn
        Button loadspec = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        loadspec.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                // filename input
                filepath =filename.getText().toString();

                //set file path 
                    try {
                        filepath = "/sdcard/"+filepath+".txt";
                     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
                      String specData = "";
                      int specVal;
                      int channelVal=1;
                      while ((specData = br.readLine()) != null) {

                          // Method for converting the text read from file to an integer
                          specVal=scatter.StringToNumber(specData);
                          // adding points to XYseries
                          scatter.addPoints(channelVal, specVal);
                          //repainting the view;
                          view.repaint();
                          //setting the specData string to an empty string
                          specData="";
                          //incrementing the channel value
                          channelVal++;

                      }
                    } 

                    catch (IOException e) {

                      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"file not found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }

        });

        // initialize exit button
        Button exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish(); // exits the application

            }
        });
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        view = scatter.getView(this);
        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        layout.addView(view);

    }

}
```

This is the ScatterGraphPlot.java file which I use for plotting the graph

```
public ScatterGraphPlot() {
        // adding series to xymultiple series dataset
        dataset.addSeries(series1);

        // customizing the points on scatter graph
        renderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        renderer.setFillPoints(true);

        // customizing the entire graph
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.WHITE);
        mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);

    }

    public GraphicalView getView(Context context) {

        //returning the graphical view to the main activity
        view = ChartFactory.getScatterChartView(context, dataset, mRenderer);
        return view;

    }

    public void addPoints(int x, int y) {

        chval = x;
        specval = y;

        //add points to series1
        series1.add(chval, specval);
    }

    //this method converts string to a number 
    int StringToNumber(String str) {
        NumConvStr = str;
        NumConvStr=NumConvStr.trim();
        try {
            RetNum = Integer.parseInt(NumConvStr);
            return RetNum;
        } 
        //ignore catch block :assuming file to be error free
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The XML file of my app is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="@string/Close" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/filename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/filename" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/filename"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/loadspec" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope someone will help me out solving this problem.

Comment: take a look at `MainActivity.java` line 89 like your stacktrace tells. Or at least tell us which line it is in your code ;) Seems like scatter or layout may be null. depending on where line 89 is

Comment: *Way* too much code, make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: +1 BIG FAN OF SSCCE.org ;) @BaummitAugen

Comment: It seems to be the `super.onStart()` call inside the `onStart` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspecting your stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.example.spec1readertest.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:89)
```

I think the field `scatter` is never assigend a value. This will be the source of your NPE.
The following change should do the trick.

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    scatter = // initialize your scatter here first!
    view = scatter.getView(this);
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    layout.addView(view);
}
```